# How to transfer integers from textbox into listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, listbox

I am trying to make this so the user will input values into two different textboxs, the values will be multiplied by each other and the result will be placed into a listbox.

I've tried to make this code work a few ways but with no luck:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM pets", cs);
        cs.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = dr;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        cs.Close();

        int dogWeight;
        dogWeight = Convert.ToInt32(petWeight.Text);
        dogWeight = int.Parse(petWeight.Text);

        int dogFood;
        dogFood = Convert.ToInt32(petFood.Text);
        dogFood = int.Parse(petFood.Text);

        int dogCosts;
        dogCosts = dogFood * dogWeight;

        ListBox1.Items.Add(dogCosts);
    }
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Exactly what doesn't work about it? You ask about two text boxes but show an example with a SQL Query so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: This method gives me two errors: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for _'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem)' has some invalid arguments.'_ and
Error 2 _Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'_
And other methods i've tried have not made the information display in the listbox with no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) into ListBox instead of integer value - dogCosts

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(dogCosts.ToString(), dogCosts.ToString()));
```

If you do not want care about `Value`, you can just create with `Text`.

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(dogCosts.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(dogCosts.ToString());
```

Also, you don't need to convert and parse the text to an int.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(dogCosts));
```